# Google DateTime Class - Date Formatting In Java

Tags: java, date, formatting, blogger

So I'm using the google blogger.com api and I have a blog post date in Google's Date Time class format.....

http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/DateTime.html

What is the easiest way in Java to format that DateTime object to display in this format?

Mar 1, 2012 12:45 PM

Comment: Intial thought was I could use the getValue method which returns the - Date/time value expressed as the number of ms since the Unix epoch. Convert it to a java util Date and do some formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the SimpleDateFormat class for format the any date format